# Extract a parameter from URL using a regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url

I have a number of links that look like:

```
<a href="http://url.com/?foo=bar&p=20" title="foo">Foo</a>
<a href="http://url2.com/?foo=bar&p=30" title="foo">Foo</a>
```

I'm trying to extract the parameter `p` from each `href` found. So in this case I have an end result array as `array (20, 30)`.

What would be a good regex for this? Thanks.

Comment: Like that? So invalid HTML? There isn't a good regex for it, use an HTML parser (one with good error recovery), extract the values of the href attributes, then run them through a URL parser.

Comment: Does `href="[^ "]+\&p=([^"]+)"` work?

Comment: You can't parse with regular expressions reliably.  See below.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Yeah that's actually pretty close! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the Simple HTML DOM Parser. I'll take a look!

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 8):

Don’t try to parse HTML with regular expressions; use an HTML parser like [PHP’s DOM library](http://php.net/book.dom) or the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead. Then parse the URL with [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and the query string with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str).

Here’s an example:

```
$html = str_get_html('…');
$p = array();
foreach ($html->find('a[href]') as $a) {
    parse_str(parse_url($a->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_QUERY), $args);
    if (isset($args['p'])) $p[] = $args['p'];
}
```